# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'lstm_3_input' with dtype float and shape [1,1,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm trying to create an ensemble model out of 3 Sequential sub models using this code:

```py
def create_ensemble(models,model_input):

    # take-in all outputs fro all models
    outModels = [model(model_input) for model in models]

    # calculate average of all results
    outAvg = layers.average(outModels)

    # merge into one model

    modelMerge = Model(inputs=model_input,outputs=outAvg,name='ensemble')

    return modelMerge


model_input = Input(shape=models[0].input_shape[1:])
modelEns = create_ensemble(models,model_input)
```

And I get this Model:

```py
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 1)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Sequential)            multiple             14          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_2 (Sequential)            multiple             14          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_3 (Sequential)            multiple             14          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_1 (Average)             (None, 1)            0           model_1[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_3[1][0]                    
==================================================================================================
```

The sub models are all as follows:

```py
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (1, 1)                    12        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (1, 1)                    2         
=================================================================
```

Here's how I feed data:

```py
def fit_lstm(train, batch_size, nb_epoch, nb_neurons):
    X, y = train[:, 0:-1], train[:, -1]
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(nb_neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    for i in range(nb_epoch):
        model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
        model.reset_states()
    return model
```

I'm trying to feed the ensemble model the same data I did for the sub model but I get the error in the title. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: How do you feed the data? Using `tf.Session()` or `model.fit()`? You need to show how do you feed the data since the problem is there. The code that you've provided seems correct.

Comment: I edited the post with the function I use to feed data

Comment: In this example you aren't feeding the ensemble model but just a regular model. + What are the shapes of `X` and `y` that go into `model.fit()`. + Do you have problem running this particular code that you've just appended?

Comment: I use this function to feed the 3 lstm models and not the ensemble model. What I want is to feed the ensemble model X (same X for the 3 sub models) that will then be fed to all of the three sub models to get the output. When I feed X to the 3 sub models I get what I want but when I try X on the ensemble model I get the error. X is shape (28,1,1)

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work because you are using the [**`Sequestial`**](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) api:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

In order to merge models together you need to use the [**`Functional`**](https://keras.io/models/model/) api:

```
a = Input(shape=(32,))
b = Dense(32)(a)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)
```

Comment: it's actually possible as specified in Keras documentation. It's just that I already have my 3 trained models saved whereas in the documentation it's trying to train the ensemble model in the beginning. I am now at the predicting phase (on new data)